# Why do stringr and purrr functions only work together when I create a function?

Tags: r, function, stringr, purrr

While working on a text-based data frame, I noticed that the functions str_remove_all and modify only work together when  I create a function that uses str_remove_all, and I'm wondering if anyone can explain why that is.  For example:

```
favoriteFruit <- c("apple", "banana", "favorite is banana", "strawberry", "favorite is apple")
favoriteVeg <- c("carrot", "carrot", "celery", "favorite is celery", "corn")
name <- c("Carlie", "Daniel", "Ellen", "Theo", "CiCi")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(name, favoriteFruit, favoriteVeg), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(df)
 name      favoriteFruit        favoriteVeg
1 Carlie              apple             carrot
2 Daniel             banana             carrot
3  Ellen favorite is banana             celery
4   Theo         strawberry favorite is celery
5   CiCi  favorite is apple               corn
```

Now, if I want to go through the data frame and remove all instances of "favorite is," I can use the following:

```
cleanerFunc <- function(column) {
  new <- str_remove_all(column, "favorite is ")
  return(new)
}
df2 <- modify(df, cleanerFunc) %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(df2)
name favoriteFruit favoriteVeg
1 Carlie         apple      carrot
2 Daniel        banana      carrot
3  Ellen        banana      celery
4   Theo    strawberry      celery
5   CiCi         apple        corn
```

Creating that function seems like a step I should be able to skip, since the function only does one thing (i.e. tell R to use a single different function).  It seems to me that I should be able to skip the creation of the function and use str_remove_all directly with modify, but all my attempts to do this return errors or empty data frames (see below).

Obviously, creating the function is a pretty simple workaround, so I'm mostly asking because I want to know what I've misunderstood that made me think I could skip that step.  Can anyone explain what the creation of that cleanerFunc changes?

Other ways I tried to clean my data frame:

```
df3 <- modify(df, str_remove_all("favorite is "))
df4 <- modify(df, str_remove_all(., "favorite is"))
df5 <- modify(df, str_remove_all(df, "favorite is"))
df6 <- df %>%
  modify(str_remove_all(., "favorite is"))
df7 <- df %>%
  modify(str_remove_all(., "favorite is")) %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to the help `?purrr::modify` you have to specify a function, formula, or atomic vector.

If a function, it is used as is. So use

```
modify(df, str_remove_all, pattern="favorite is ")
```

If a formula, e.g. ~ .x + 2, it is converted to a function. Thus try

```
modify(df, ~str_remove_all(.,"favorite is "))
```

Or simply use `mutate`

```
df %>% mutate_all(funs(str_remove_all(.,"favorite is ")))
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the main problems with my other attempts (df3, df4, etc.) were that I was structuring it incorrectly.  I'm looking through the help docs for purrr::modify and it says that you can add "additional arguments passed on to .f", which I've seen in a lot of other help docs for other functions and packages.  Does that always mean that you write the arguments separated from the function by a comma (like you did in your first code block), never in parentheses after the function (like I tried to for df3)?

Comment: Yes, mostly you have to write additional arguments like described. Sometimes you have to add further parameters in a list.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `str_remove_all`'s signature is `string, pattern`. This means your calls to `modify` are all trying to manipulate the same constant ("favorite is"). Your approach (with the `cleanerFunc`) is a valid way to resolve the issue.